# How Do I Embed Expo Snacks In HTML Page

Tags: html, iframe, expo

could someone please tell me how I could embed only my Expo Snack's output in HTML?
I tried this =>

```html
<iframe src = "https://snack-web-player.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/43/index.html?initialUrl=exp%3A%2F%2Fexp.host%2F%40jothamsamuel%2Ftsst%2B238_!hBTJ7&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fsnack.expo.dev&verbose=false"></iframe>
```

but did not work as expected.
It was only showing this = >

[image]

> PS: I got the link by clicking on : [image]

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/expo/snack/blob/main/docs/embedding-snacks.md) to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

## How To Embed Expo Snacks In HTML Page

First click on Android option.[image]

Then click on the new window option. [image]

Then copy the URL.`https://appetize.io/embed/..........`

And then your code should be like the following.

```css
    iframe{
      width:330px;
      height:700px;
      border:none;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
    <center><h1>Embedding Expo Snacks With Only The Output </h1>
    <iframe src = "https://appetize.io/embed/xc1w6f1krd589zhp22a0mgftyw?autoplay=false&debug=true&device=pixel4&embed=true&launchUrl=exp%3A%2F%2Fexp.host%2F%40jothamsamuel%2Fhtmlview%2BBECEXjHOGk&scale=81&screenOnly=false&xDocMsg=true&xdocMsg=true&params=%7B%22EXDevMenuDisableAutoLaunch%22%3Atrue%2C%22EXKernelLaunchUrlDefaultsKey%22%3A%22exp%3A%2F%2Fexp.host%2F%40jothamsamuel%2Fhtmlview%2BBECEXjHOGk%22%2C%22EXKernelDisableNuxDefaultsKey%22%3Atrue%7D&osVersion=11.0" ></iframe></center>
```

[image]